# SCNVideoNode playing extremely fast

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, scenekit, vuforia

I'm trying to show a video in augmented reality using Vuforia - but for the sake of this question, just showing the scene and video would be fine.

What's expected:
Show the video (playing) at the correct speed for video and audio and have them both in sync.

What's happening:
Audio plays at correct speed. Video plays at a seriously fast speed - like 10x.

Tried:

- I've tried changing the rate - it's ignored completely.
- I've tried using different ways (AVPlayer, AVPlayerLayer,
  SKVideoNode(withURL)) of putting the video into the scene - all
  suffer from hyperactive-video-syndrome
- I've tried other file formats - nope
- I've tried local files and URL - no dice
- I've tried throwing my laptop at a wall - it made the video go away

Code to return a the scene with the video:

```
private func createVideoScene(with view: VuforiaEAGLView) -> SCNScene {
        // create the asset & player and grab the dimensions
        let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(string: "https://inm-baobab-prod-eu-west-1.s3.amazonaws.com/public/inm/media/video/2016/09/02/61537094SansSouciGirlsSchool.mp4")!)
        let size = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))

        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player)
        videoNode.size = size
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)

        let videoScene = SKScene(size: size)
        videoScene.addChild(videoNode)

        let videoWrapperNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 10, height: 8))
        videoWrapperNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        videoWrapperNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =  videoScene
        videoWrapperNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.doubleSided = true
        videoWrapperNode.scale.y = -1
        videoWrapperNode.name = "video"

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(videoWrapperNode)
        return scene
    }
```

Thank you

PS. Help in Objective-C is also welcome :)

Comment: plus one for humour! more if i could